# Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST

Tags: axios, ethereum, ipfs, nft, pinata

I've followed the alchemy NFT marketplace course (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6JfVdcJh1k&t=262s and https://github.com/alchemyplatform/RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace) successfully but somehow the app stopped working and I am now getting an axis error which appears to be coming from the axios get request for the NFT tokenURI (IPFS pinata link containing the NFT metadata) in Marketplace.js coming from the line:

> let meta = await axios.get(tokenURI);

I have been looking for a solution for two days and can not figure out why it is not working anymore. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting the below error:

```
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmVEA6DxgG6QiPB56E6gP6V7AfeF5D82TXrNML7fzSFPV5
Marketplace.js:69 
xhr.js:220          GET https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmVEA6DxgG6QiPB56E6gP6V7AfeF5D82TXrNML7fzSFPV5 400
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:109
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:131
wrap @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ Marketplace.js:70
await in (anonymous) (async)
getAllNFTs @ Marketplace.js:63
await in getAllNFTs (async)
Marketplace @ Marketplace.js:95
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
Marketplace.js:91 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
getAllNFTs @ Marketplace.js:91
await in getAllNFTs (async)
Marketplace @ Marketplace.js:95
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
xhr.js:220          GET https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmVEA6DxgG6QiPB56E6gP6V7AfeF5D82TXrNML7fzSFPV5 400
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:220
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:109
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:131
wrap @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ Marketplace.js:70
await in (anonymous) (async)
getAllNFTs @ Marketplace.js:63
await in getAllNFTs (async)
Marketplace @ Marketplace.js:95
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20145
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
Marketplace.js:91 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

See below the code from the Marketplace.js file:

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import NFTTile from "./NFTTile";
// import MarketplaceJSON from "../Marketplace_goerli.json";
import MarketplaceJSON from "../Marketplace_localhost.json";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Marketplace() {
  const sampleData = [
    {
      name: "NFT#1",
      description: "Alchemy's First NFT",
      website: "http://axieinfinity.io",
      image:
        "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmTsRJX7r5gyubjkdmzFrKQhHv74p5wT9LdeF1m3RTqrE5",
      price: "0.03ETH",
      currentlySelling: "True",
      address: "0xe81Bf5A757CB4f7F82a2F23b1e59bE45c33c5b13",
    },
    {
      name: "NFT#2",
      description: "Alchemy's Second NFT",
      website: "http://axieinfinity.io",
      image:
        "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmdhoL9K8my2vi3fej97foiqGmJ389SMs55oC5EdkrxF2M",
      price: "0.03ETH",
      currentlySelling: "True",
      address: "0xe81Bf5A757C4f7F82a2F23b1e59bE45c33c5b13",
    },
    {
      name: "NFT#3",
      description: "Alchemy's Third NFT",
      website: "http://axieinfinity.io",
      image:
        "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmTsRJX7r5gyubjkdmzFrKQhHv74p5wT9LdeF1m3RTqrE5",
      price: "0.03ETH",
      currentlySelling: "True",
      address: "0xe81Bf5A757C4f7F82a2F23b1e59bE45c33c5b13",
    },
  ];
  const [data, updateData] = useState(sampleData);
  const [dataFetched, updateFetched] = useState(false);

  async function getAllNFTs() {
    const ethers = require("ethers");
    //After adding your Hardhat network to your metamask, this code will get providers and signers
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    //Pull the deployed contract instance
    let contract = new ethers.Contract(
      MarketplaceJSON.address,
      MarketplaceJSON.abi,
      signer
    );

    //create an NFT Token
    let transaction = await contract.getAllNFTs();

    //Fetch all the details of every NFT from the contract and display
    const items = await Promise.all(
      transaction.map(async (i) => {
        const tokenURI = await contract.tokenURI(i.tokenId);
        console.log(tokenURI);
        let meta = await axios.get(tokenURI);
        meta = meta.data;
        console.log(` The tokenURI metadata are: ${meta}`);

        let price = ethers.utils.formatUnits(i.price.toString(), "ether");
        let item = {
          price,
          tokenId: i.tokenId.toNumber(),
          seller: i.seller,
          owner: i.owner,
          image: meta.image,
          name: meta.name,
          description: meta.description,
        };
        return item;
      })
    );

    updateFetched(true);
    updateData(items);
  }

  if (!dataFetched) getAllNFTs();

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div className="flex flex-col place-items-center mt-20">
        <div className="md:text-xl font-bold text-white">Top NFTs</div>
        <div className="flex mt-5 justify-between flex-wrap max-w-screen-xl text-center">
          {data.map((value, index) => {
            return <NFTTile data={value} key={index}></NFTTile>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `console.log(tokenURI)` can you copy the tokenURI and paste it to the browser see if you get the data

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did this and get the below tokenURI which works in the browser: https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmVEA6DxgG6QiPB56E6gP6V7AfeF5D82TXrNML7fzSFPV5

Comment: The issue appears to be coming from the axios call which either return a 429 error or a 400 error (if a do just a single call).

Comment: FYI this was likely due to too many calls to the smart contract function.
I am now using the Moralis API to retrieve NFT data which is much more efficient that doing it with custom made smart contract functions.
The front end can now retrieve the data I want efficiently thanks to the Moralis NFT API.

Comment: I have the same issue, however it does seem that the file is successfully retrieved, but the error is still thrown. We ended up uploading the file to S3 as a cache, and so successive tries do work - do you see an issue with "settle"?

Comment: Can you wrap the call in a `try/catch` statement and print out the error to the console?

Answer (score 0):

the error might be related to this: [how-to-fix-400-errors-with-dedicated-gateways](https://knowledge.pinata.cloud/en/articles/6848516-how-to-fix-400-errors-with-dedicated-gateways)

when you make a request to pinata you have to add this header:

```
const res = await axios.get(tokenURI, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/plain'
      }
    })
```